# Beginner mod_rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

how would I rewrite in .htaccess:

```
url.com/NAME to url.com/view.php?=NAME
```

I've tried a couple of variations but I think i might be putting a slash in the wrong place.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /view.php?somevar=$1 [L]
```

You have to set NAME as the value of some variable.

This example allows NAME to be any word.. if you want something specific... just replace \w+ with whatever specific thing you want.